# React: Update state variables shorthand

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

In React, to handle variable changes, we do:

```
handleChangeRound = (round) => {
  this.setState({round: round});
}

updateLoading = (isLoading) => {
  this.setState({isLoading: isLoading});
}
```

Is there a way to write

```
this.setState({round: round});
this.setState({isLoading: isLoading});
```

as

```
this.updateState(round);
this.updateState(isLoading);
```

given the variables `round` and `isLoading` exist in the state and correspond to the variable name to avoid the redundant `variable: variable`?

---

PS: Inspired by:

```
console.log({x: x, y: y});
// output:
// {x: 10, y:20}
```

can be written as

```
console.log({x,y});
// output:
// {x: 10, y:20}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can write it as

```
this.setState({round});
this.setState({isLoading});
```

by using the Object Property Shorthand from ECMAScript 6 / ES2015. Basically the idea behind this is that you can omit the property key since the variable declaration *has* the key.

[Property definitions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#New_notations_in_ECMAScript_2015)

Comment: I assume you misInterpreted the question.

Comment: @murat-karagöz so this syntax `{variable}` is applicable wherever the pattern `{variable:variable}` appears? I mean, is it an ES6 spec or something?

Comment: @SaravanabalagiRamachandran Yes it's possible with the new Ecmascript.

Comment: What do we call this: Is there a specific name for this? Also, it would be great if you can update the answer with its generic applicability so it would be useful for others :)

Comment: @SaravanabalagiRamachandran Updated the answer.

Answer (score 0):

All you need is to write setState with a dynamic obj and pass in an object to the function like

```
this.updateState({ round });
this.updateState({ isLoading });

updateState = (obj) => {
   this.setState(obj)
}
```

[**Sample Demo**](https://codesandbox.io/s/rrwv6q22vn)

Comment: what do you gain by creating an additional method that seemingly does exactly the same?

Comment: @TimCastelijns, This can be used as a generic method, instead of having different methods like `handleChangeRound` , `updateLoading`

Answer (score 0):

you can use setState with call back

```
this.setState(prevState => {
 return {
   isLoading:!prevState.isLoading
 }
})
```

or you can do what ever from the prevState